# after successful login keep redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to redirect my program to "https://uptobox.com/?op=my_account" page after logging in but keep redirecting me to the login page 
i tried

```
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

and using the login cookies into the request of redirecting but not working
the problem is after login a set-cookies generated in the header i don't know how to inject that into the redirecting request & i'm using win form app

```
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "login=" + username + "&password=" + pw +"&op=login";
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.uptobox.com/logarithme");
            request.Method = "POST";
            CookieContainer mycoockie = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer = mycoockie;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string source_code = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Did you try context.Redirect?

Comment: i'm not working with asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is : to add the set-cookies generated in the header response from a successful login to the new request .

```
request.Headers.Add("cookie", "value");
```